# Why we can find a permutation with $2$ fix points in this way?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, permutation-cycles

I have a permutation of order $20$ and I can make cyclic permutation on it. For example $(3 2 1)$ should be $(2 1 3)$ or $(1 3 2)$. Why we can find a permutation with $2$ fix points in this way?

This is not available for a permutation of order $3$.
I have the next context: I have $20$ people on a round table and $20$ papers with their names. I can rotate the table s.t. two of them have the right names?

Comment: If you do a cyclic permutation there will be no fixed points.  There are permutations of $20$ objects with $2$ fixed points, but they are not cyclic.  There are no permutations of $3$ objects with $2$ fixed points, or generally there are no permutations of $n$ objects with $n-1$ fixed points, because once you fix $n-1$ the only place to put the last one is where it belongs.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: I agree with @RossMillikan that this needs to be clarified. In particular, what do you mean by "making" a permutation on another permutation? The most likely meaning of this would be conjugating the latter by the former, but that will never produce fixed points if there were none to begin with. Maybe you meant composing the two permutations, but if so, in which order? Or did you mean  something entirely different?

Comment: See this Matt Parker video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9xw7vupte2Q

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer, but too long for a comment.

To have a permutation that you cannot rotate to get two elements right, each element must be displaced by a different amount from its correct location.  That is easy to do if the number of elements is odd.  Let $1$ be the element that is in its correct location.   Then offset each element by one more than the previous one, rolling around the circle at the end.  For $9$ elements, the permutation is $(135792468)$.  It should be clear how this matches your example for $3$ and any other odd number.

This construction fails for even numbers because when you get done with the odds you get back to $1$.  That does not prove there is not some other permutation that satisfies your requirement.  We can see it does not work for $4$ by exhausting the cases.  Again, let $1$ stay fixed.  If $2$ goes to $3$, we cannot have $3$ go to $1$ because $4$ would have to stay fixed.  We cannot have $3$ go to $4$ because rotating one step counterclockwise would make both $2$ and $3$ right, so $3$ goes to $2$.  But then $4$ must stay fixed and we already have two fixed points.  There was nothing special about $2$ going to $3$ so any other choice will run into the same problem.

I suspect the general proof goes through the sum of the displacements.  If there are $n$ elements, the sum of the displacements is $\frac 12n(n-1)$.  If $n$ is odd, this is divisible by $n$, while if $n$ is even it is not.  I can't find the argument to say the sum must be divisible by $n$, but I think it is standard.

Comment: Proof the sum of the displacements is divisible by n: Any adjacent transposition does not change this sum modulo n (one displacement is incremented, another decremented). The modulo n is necessary since a displacement of n is equivalent to zero displacement. Every permutation is achievable as a product of adjacent transpositions. Therefore the sum of the displacements is constant modulo n, and the same for all permutations. The identity permutation has zero total displacement, so the sum of the displacements is always 0 modulo n, i.e. divisible by n.